# failed to delete file by os.remove(), with PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I use python 3.6 and opencv 3.4.0 to process some video.
My main task is detect the upperbody in a video and judge if the average width of those rectangles in each frame is large enough, if it is too small, I will delect this video.
And this is my code.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import glob as gb
import shutil
import os

cf2 = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Lib\site-packages\opencvhaartemp\haarcascades\haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml")


def renew(avw,count,w):
    return (count*avw+w)/(count+1)

def discern(img,avw,count,fps,size):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    upperRects = cf2.detectMultiScale(
        gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(50, 50))
    if len(upperRects):        
        for upperRect in upperRects:
            x, y, w, h = upperRect
            avw=renew(avw,count,w)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + h, y + w), (0, 255, 0), 2)  # mark every body by rectangle       
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    return avw

video_path=gb.glob("D:\\onedrive\\codes\\spider\\opencv\\*avi")
for path in video_path:
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

    fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    size = (int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

    success, frame = video.read()
    avew=0.0
    count=0.0

    while success : #display frame by frame
        avew=discern(frame,avew,count,fps,size)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        success, frame = video.read()
        count=count+1

    print("average width:",avew/size[0])
    if (avew/size[0]<0.2):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # release windows
        os.remove(path)
```

And then I got the following error information

```
File "d:\onedrive\codes\spider\opencv\upper.py", line 68, in <module>
os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I don't know how to release the other process that occupies the video I want to delete , I don't even know which process is occupying the video.

Also  please help me with

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if this cannot end the process that occupies the video I want to delete, what can it do then?

---

I fixed the problem by adding

```
video.release()
```

before delete the video.

It occurred to me that video objection may need to be released when I saw a demo of open camera in VideoCapture objection, I found the coder release the VideoCapture objection before closing all image windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting your VideoCapture object before removing file.

```
del video
os.remove(path)
```

Comment: I just found the VideoCapture object has an operation of release, and I fixed the problem by adding it. Thank you after all !